# Python: Extract alternate columns from a file

Tags: python

I want to extract all doubles/floats from a file. Any line looks like:

```
0    324.609    1    -39475.435    2     23.439    3    983.098
4    -4384.698    5    9475.405    6     2398.349    7    9800.138
...
```

Right now, I am building lists out of columns:

```
    y1 = [ line.split()[1] for line in data]
    y2 = [ line.split()[3] for line in data]
    y3 = [ line.split()[5] for line in data]
    y4 = [ line.split()[7] for line in data]
```

However, the index goes out of range if there is no column 7. How do I prevent this? Also, is there a better way of extracting all double (with the `-` sign) from a file?

Thank you.

Comment: What values from the example you gave are supposed to be part of `y1`?

Comment: @James `324.609`, `-4384.698`

Comment: Are you opposed to using any libraries?  There are some good options out there that would make this trivial.

Comment: @IraWoodring, which ones in particular?

Comment: Pandas (as listed by the reply below) and numpy make it much easier to work with data.  If you don't have any requirements to not use libraries I'd go with one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spare yourself from the misery of parsing a mal-formatted data file by using Pandas. In the following example, I assume that the second line of the file does not have the last two columns:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table("yourfile.dat", sep='\s+', header=None, index_col=None)
#   0         1  2          3  4         5    6        7
#0  0   324.609  1 -39475.435  2    23.439  3.0  983.098
#1  4 -4384.698  5   9475.405  6  2398.349  NaN      NaN

y1 = data[1].dropna().tolist()
y2 = data[3].dropna().tolist()
y3 = data[5].dropna().tolist()
y4 = data[7].dropna().tolist()
y4
#[983.0980000000001]
```

Answer (score 0):

To save alternate columns, generate a list of odd numbers.

```
    L = list(range(10)) 
    y1 = []
    for lines in data:
        line = lines.split()
        n = len(line)
        l = L[1:n:2]
        for i in l:
            y1.append(line[i])
    print y1
```

y1 is a list of all numbers in odd columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a try/except block when iterating over each line.

```
y7 = []
for line in data:
    try:
        y7.append(float(line.split()[7]))
    except:
        pass
```

If there is no seventh column, then it won't give you an error.

---

If you want to keep the order of each number (for example if you want every element in the 7th row to be the 7th elements of your lists), then you could append np.nan to your list:

```
y7 = []
for line in data:
    try:
        y7.append(float(line.split()[7]))
    except:
        y7.append(np.nan)
```